# Easiest way to adjust the p-values for multiple comparisons for model(s) to be shown with msummary from modelsummary package

Tags: r, regression, lme4, lmertest, modelsummary

Having used `lmerTest::lmer()` to perform linear regression with repeated measures data I would like to adjust for multiple comparisons.
I ran several models and used Bonferroni-Holm to adjust each of them, see my approach below.
Eventually, I would like to generate a regression table with [modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html) which should include the adjusted p-values and additional goodness-of-fit statistics (alike in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723430/how-to-extract-the-goodness-of-fit-statistics-from-lmer-model-for-msummary-fro/65725091#65725091)).

*– Maybe there is also a much easier way in `modelsummary()` to adjust the p-values that I am not aware of yet?*
(both for models individually as well as for/across a group of models altogether)

#### MWE

```
library("modelsummary")
library("lmerTest") 
library("parameters")
library("performance")

mod1  <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + (1 | cyl), data = mtcars) 
mod2  <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + (1 | gear), data = mtcars) 

l_mod <- list("mod1" = mod1, "mod2" = mod2)
# msummary(l_mod) # works well

adjMC <- function( model ) {
model_glht <- glht(model)
model_mc_adj <- summary(model_glht, test = adjusted('holm')) # Bonferroni-Holm is less conservative and uniformly more powerful than Bonferroni
return(model_mc_adj)
}
mod1_adj <- adjMC(mod1)
mod2_adj <- adjMC(mod2)

l_mod_adj <- list("mod1_adj" = mod1_adj, "mod2_adj" = mod2_adj)
```

However, upon adjusting the p-values the class from the model changes from "lmerModLmerTest" to "summary.glht"

```
class(mod1) # => "lmerModLmerTest"
class(mod1_adj) # => "summary.glht"
```

"summary.glht" is among the [list of supported models of modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#supported-models-1),
and I succeed in obtaining the estimates and p-values:

```
parameters::model_parameters(mod1_adj)
# Parameter        | Coefficient |   SE |         95% CI | Statistic | df |      p
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# (Intercept) == 0 |       24.71 | 3.13 | [17.84, 31.57] |      7.89 |  0 | < .001
# hp == 0          |       -0.03 | 0.01 | [-0.06,  0.00] |     -2.09 |  0 | 0.064
# e.g. with modelsummary:
modelsummary::get_estimates(mod1_adj) # gives more info than broom::tidy(mod1_adj)
```

However, obtaining the goodness-of-fit statistics did not succeed:

```
performance::model_performance(mod1_adj)
# 'r2()' does not support models of class 'summary.glht'.
# Can't extract residuals from model.
# no 'nobs' method is availableModels of class 'summary.glht' are not yet supported.NULL

broom::glance(mod1_adj) # and also for broom.mixed::glance(mod1_adj)
# => Error: No glance method for objects of class summary.glht

# e.g. with modelsummary:
modelsummary::get_gof(mod1_adj) 
# => Cannot extract information from models of class "summary.glht".
```

To be able to include the adjusted p-values in the final regression table I tried to generate a custom class for "summary.glht" with custom functions to extract estimates and goodness-of-fit information.
I scanned `summary(mod1_adj)` for the required information, e.g., `summary(mod1_adj)$coef` but did not find all the info needed to create the fcts.

```
names(mod1_adj$test)
# [1] "pfunction"    "qfunction"    "coefficients" "sigma"        "tstat"        "pvalues"      "type" 

tidy.summary.glht <- function(x, ...) {
    s <- summary(x, ...)
    ret <- tibble::tibble(term = ...,
                          estimate = s$test$coefficients,
                          ...      = ... ,
                          p-values = s$test$pvalues)
    ret
}

glance.summary.glht <- function(x, ...) {
  data.frame(
    "Model" = "summary.glht",
    ... = ...,
    "nobs" = stats::nobs(x)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `broom` package does have a `tidy` method for `glht` models, but does *not* have a `glance` method for such models. Since it is only *partially* supported, `modelsummary` can only extract estimates, but not goodness-of-fit statistics, so it breaks. To see this, you could try the `get_gof` and `get_estimates` from `modelsummary` on a `ghlt` object.

In contrast, `modelsummary` can easily extract both estimates and goodness-of-fit from `lmerModLmerTest` models. One approach would thus be to pass a `lmerModLmerTest` object to `modelsummary`, but to modify the p values on the fly by defining a [`tidy_custom.CLASSNAME` method as described in the `modelsummary` documentation.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#customizing-existing-models-part-i-)

Estimate model:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(lmerTest) 
library(multcomp)

mod  <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + (1 | cyl), data = mtcars)
```

Then, we define a `tidy_custom` method appropriate for your model class (again, see the documentation linked above for details).

Note that, for some reason, the term names are modified slightly when extracting results from a `glht` object instead of a `lmerModLmerTest` model. This is a problem in the upstream package, so you may want to report it there (not sure if it's `broom` or `performance`, but it would be easy to check). In any case, this is easy to fix for our purposes by simply adding a `gsub` call to our new method:

```r
tidy_custom.lmerModLmerTest <- function(x, ...) {
  new <- multcomp::glht(x)
  new <- summary(new, test = adjusted('holm'))
  out <- get_estimates(new)
  out$term <- gsub(" == 0", "", out$term)
  out
}

modelsummary(mod, statistic = "p.value")
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 24.708 |
|  | (0.000) |
| hp | -0.030 |
|  | (0.064) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 Marg. | 0.143 |
| R2 Cond. | 0.674 |
| AIC | 181.9 |
| BIC | 187.8 |
| ICC | 0.6 |

Comment: Thank you for the quick and informative response! This got me a lot closer! If I employ your code I receive the following error though: `Error in sanity_tidy(est, est_custom, estimate, statistic, class(model)[1]): Assertion on 'tidy_custom' failed: Must have exactly 4 rows, but has 2 rows.` What am I missing?

Comment: Complete error message: `7. stop(simpleError(sprintf(msg, ...), call.))
6. mstop("Assertion on '%s' failed: %s.", var.name, res, call. = sys.call(-2L))
5. makeAssertion(x, res, .var.name, add)
4. checkmate::assert_data_frame(tidy_custom, nrows=nrow(tidy_output), min.cols=2, null.ok=T)
3. sanity_tidy(est, est_custom, estimate, statistic, class(model)[1])
2. extract_estimates(model=models[[i]], fmt=fmt, estimate=estimate[[i]], statistic=statistic, vcov=vcov[[i]], conf_level=conf_level, stars=stars, ...)
1. modelsummary(mod, statistic = "p.value") `

Comment: Thanks that's useful. I just pushed a new version of the package to Github. Could you install it and try again? After you install, make sure you restart the R session completely and that none of your old objects are loaded (through history or `.RData` for example.  `library(remotes);install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try just now and report back. Am also using your great plotting ct `modelsummary::modelplot()`. Is there a way to have a different symbol for each model in the plot?

Comment: The [website shows many ways to customize the output of `modelplot`](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelplot.html). But to be perfectly honest, when I really want to customize things, I just do `modelplot(mod, draw=FALSE)`. That gives me a clean data frame that I can feed immediately to `ggplot2`.

Comment: Also, will try the `modelplot(mod, draw=FALSE)` version. For some reason, `modelplot(list(model_A,model_B))` would mix up the order of models, such that the coefficients for model_A would have the colors for model_B, which is very misleading (luckily noticed since the summary table with the correct coefficients for each model was placed just above in the report).

Comment: Weird. I have never seen that color mix up before. If you could submit an issue to github with a replicable example that would be super useful. Now worries if impossible.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/200) - thanks for any advice!