# Extracting information from R objects and importing it to a modelsummary table

Tags: r, modelsummary

I am trying to make a statistical model summary table using the `modelsummary` package.

I ran 6 regressions. I conducted joint hypothesis tests for 2 of them, which include certain variables (specificaly, `educ` and `exper`) as explanatory variables. I want to include the F statistics from those tests in the table, but have trouble extracting information from the tests and importing it into the table.

Here are some more details.

(1) What I did, part 1: Packages, data, and analyses

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wooldridge)   # Data
library(estimatr)     # Estimation
library(car)          # F test
library(modelsummary) # Table
library(kableExtra)   # Table

wage2 <- wage2 %>% 
  mutate(lwage = log(wage))

model1 <- lm_robust(lwage ~ educ, 
                    data = wage2, se_type = "HC1")
model2 <- lm_robust(lwage ~ exper, 
                    data = wage2, se_type = "HC1")
model3 <- lm_robust(lwage ~ educ + exper, 
                    data = wage2, se_type = "HC1")
F3 <- linearHypothesis(model3, test = "F", 
                       c("educ = 0", "exper = 0"))
model4 <- lm_robust(lwage ~ educ + tenure, 
                    data = wage2, se_type = "HC1")
model5 <- lm_robust(lwage ~ exper + tenure, 
                    data = wage2, se_type = "HC1")
model6 <- lm_robust(lwage ~ educ + exper + tenure, 
                    data = wage2, se_type = "HC1")
F6 <- linearHypothesis(model6, test = "F", 
                       c("educ = 0", "exper = 0"))
```

The results of the joint hypothesis tests are as follows.

```
F3
```

```
## Linear hypothesis test
## 
## Hypothesis:
## educ = 0
## exper = 0
## 
## Model 1: restricted model
## Model 2: lwage ~ educ + exper
## 
##   Res.Df Df      F    Pr(>F)    
## 1    934                        
## 2    932  2 67.715 < 2.2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

```
F6
```

```
## Linear hypothesis test
## 
## Hypothesis:
## educ = 0
## exper = 0
## 
## Model 1: restricted model
## Model 2: lwage ~ educ + exper + tenure
## 
##   Res.Df Df      F    Pr(>F)    
## 1    933                        
## 2    931  2 63.592 < 2.2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

(2) What I did, part 2: Table

```
regs <- list()
regs[['Model 1']] <- model1
regs[['Model 2']] <- model2
regs[['Model 3']] <- model3
regs[['Model 4']] <- model4
regs[['Model 5']] <- model5
regs[['Model 6']] <- model6

gm <- tribble(
  ~raw, ~clean, ~fmt,
  "adj.r.squared", "$\\bar{R}^2$", 3,
  "nobs", "Sample size", 0
  )

rows <- tribble(
  ~term, ~'Model 1', ~'Model 2', ~'Model 3', 
  ~'Model 4', ~'Model 5', ~'Model 6', 
  '$F$ statstics', '', '', '', '', '', '',
  '$H_0: \\beta_{\\rm{educ}} = 0, \\beta_{\\rm{exper}} = 0$', 
  '', '', '67.715***', '', '', '63.592***',
  '', '', '', '(0.000)', '', '', '(0.000)'
)
attr(rows, 'position') <- c(9:11)

table <- msummary(regs, 
         estimate = "{estimate}{stars}",
         gof_map = gm, 
         notes = list("*** p < 0.01, ** p < 0.05, * p < 0.1. 
                      Heteroskedasticity-consistent 
                      standard errors in brackets. 
                      P values in brackets for F statistics."),
         add_rows = rows) %>% 
  row_spec(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10), 
           extra_css = "border-bottom: hidden") 
table
```

The above code gave me a nice table. (Unfortunately, I do not seem to be able to post it because I have not earned enough reputation.)

(3) What I want to know

In the above, I manually typed in the F statistics, stars, and p-values in `rows` to obtain the table I wanted, but I would like to find out if there is a way to extract information from `F3` and `F6` and import it to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

1. Add two rows to the bottom of the table: F statistic and associated p-value
2. These rows should be added only to some models, which you pick manually

The simplest way to achieve this is to use the `add_rows` argument you use in your example. Your approach is correct!

If you want a more general and automated strategy, [you can define a `glance_custom.lm_robust` method.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#adding-new-information-to-existing-models-1)

Your example was complicated, so I took the liberty of simplifying it to turn it into a [Minimal Reproducible Example.](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html) You will notice that I create and check a new attribute to determine which models will have a linear hypothesis test in the table.

(Note: answering your question led me to discover a minor bug which mixed the order of rows at the bottom of the table. This bug is now fixed. The table pasted below was produced using the development version of `modelsummary` 0.9.2.9000, which you can install by calling: `remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")`  )

```
library(modelsummary)
library(estimatr)
library(tibble)
library(car)

mod1 <- lm_robust(mpg ~ am + vs, mtcars)
mod2 <- lm_robust(mpg ~ am + vs + hp, mtcars)
mod3 <- lm_robust(mpg ~ am + vs + wt, mtcars)
mod4 <- lm_robust(mpg ~ am + vs + qsec, mtcars)

# models 2 and 4 will have a linear hypothesis test
attr(mod2, "FTEST") <- TRUE
attr(mod4, "FTEST") <- TRUE

glance_custom.lm_robust <- function(x) {
  # check if we should include the linear hypothesis test in this specific model
  if (!isTRUE(attr(x, "FTEST"))) return(NULL)

  # conduct linear hypothesis test
  ftest <- linearHypothesis(x, test = "F", c("am = 0", "vs = 0"))

  # return a 1-row tibble with each statistic in separate columns
  out <- tibble(
    "$H_0: \\beta_{\\rm{vs}} = 0, \\beta_{\\rm{am}} = 0$" = ftest[["F"]][2],
    "     " = sprintf("(%.3f)", ftest[["Pr(>F)"]][2]))
  return(out)
}

modelsummary(list(mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4), escape = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. That's basically what I wanted to do. 

I have a further question. I actually want the F statistics at the top of the GOF statistics (i.e. between the regression coefficients and the number of observations). Presumably, I should use the `gof_map` argument, but I am not sure how. I would be most grateful if you would enlighten me on this issue.

Comment: That's right. When a statistic is not named in the default `modelsummary::gof_map`, it appears at the bottom. Just create your own `gof_map` data frame (or list), and the order will follow that automatically. The documentation about `gof_map` is very detailed, and there are several examples on the website: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#gof-map

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advice as well as your answer to another question were extremely helpful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723430/how-to-extract-the-goodness-of-fit-statistics-from-lmer-model-for-msummary-fro/65725091#65725091

I have almost reached where I wanted to go, but I do have a further question. I think I will make it another Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to export data from the model. Just call it out:

```
F3$F
```

and

```
F3$`Pr(>F)`
```

Comment: I should have made it clearer, but I was more concerned about importing the information into the table. However, thank you very much all the same.